# Implementing TCP Sticky Sessions With HAProxy to Handle SSL Pass-through Traffic

Tags: ssl, tcp, haproxy, sticky-sessions

How can we implement session stickiness in HAProxy when SSL must terminate on the backend servers? We need the stickiness because backends cannot share sessions.

**This is my original configuration:**

```
# SSL passthrough
listen https_handler
    bind 1.2.3.4:443
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    stick match src
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
    server s1 1.1.1.1:443
    server s2 1.1.1.2:443

# haproxy logs (not sticking)
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.396] fe BACKEND_Website/s1 37/0/1/3/41 200 8364
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.456] fe BACKEND_Website/s1 36/0/1/1/39 200 9082
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.456] fe BACKEND_Website/s2 35/0/1/3/39 200 2529
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.545] fe BACKEND_Website/s1 35/0/0/3/38 200 1460
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.501] fe BACKEND_Website/s2 36/0/1/1/109 200 376
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.545] fe BACKEND_Website/s1 36/0/1/1/74 200 2298
10.x.x.2:xxxxx [17/Dec/2014:19:29:41.604] fe BACKEND_Website/s1 35/0/1/2/38 200 5542
```

**The config below is my attempt to read the `src`:**

This results in a 502 Bad Gateway error. I assume, it is because the traffic is already decrypted by the time it reaches the backend.

```
# terminate SSL at HAProxy 
listen https_handler
    bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/certs.pem
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    stick match src
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
    server s1 1.1.1.1:443
    server s2 1.1.1.2:443
```

Notice that I plugged the cert to the binding. This is for HAProxy to be able to read the src and setup the stick-table. (Not sure if this is correct.) And at this point, the traffic is already decrypted.

I think the problem lies when this decrypted traffic is passed to the backend servers which expects encrypted traffic...

I have seen these suggestions:

1. **Terminate SSL at HAProxy 1.5** - not possible in my case. SSL need to be handled by the backend servers.
2. **[Use SSL Session ID to maintain stickiness.](http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/07/04/maintain-affinity-based-on-ssl-session-id/)** - I'm skeptical to try this out because I don't quite understand it yet. And it seems to be using a modified (?) version of haproxy.
3. **Use `send-proxy` directive & `X-Forward-Proto` header**. - but realized this also needs an HTTP-only backend.

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Would it be viable to make HAproxy re-encrypt the HTTP traffic towards the backend servers?

Comment: @felix-frank, This is what I'm not sure of if it's possible. I originally use just a pass-through setup. Now, I'm trying to implement sticky sessions with that.

Comment: Keep in mind that sticky sessions should only be used as a performance improvement. If a user is moved to a different backend in the middle of a session, it is ok if they experience slower responses for the first few requests after being moved, but you need to ensure that they still do receive correct responses.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to use `balance source`, but if many clients come from the same IP, it may not be very fair on your backend servers.

See http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/04/22/client-ip-persistence-or-source-ip-hash-load-balancing/ for more discussion on methods to accomplish this.

Comment: I am aware of that. My problem is stickiness doesn't work when I use HTTPS both on front and backends (My backend server needs to handle the SSL). I'll add more details to the question.

Comment: @Ianthe `balance source` cannot really not work. Unless the client is using TOR, they cannot conceivably end up on a backend that is different from their originial pick.

Comment: @FelixFrank Some providers have deployed CGN with a pool of IP addresses. In such a setup different TCP connections from the same client may be assigned different IP addresses by the CGN.

Answer (score 0):

If the root of your issue is the fact that the backend servers expect traffic to be HTTPS rather than HTTP, try [encrypting](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#5.2-ssl) the HTTP and do your regular Layer7 load balancing.

```
listen https_handler
    bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/certs.pem
    mode http
    balance leastconn
    # any stick rules you need
    server s1 1.1.1.1:443 ssl
    server s2 1.1.1.2:443 ssl
```

Easier yet - as you apparently try to stick by `src` anyway, why are you even decrypting the TCP traffic in the first place?

```
listen https
    bind 1.2.3.4:443 # <- NO ssl setting
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    stick match src
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 30m
    server s1 1.1.1.1:443 ssl
    server s2 1.1.1.2:443 ssl
```

In TCP mode, you don't care about the payload. Specifically, you don't care whether it's encrypted and how.

Comment: your second example was my original setup but for some reason it's not sticking. I assume it's because traffic is encrypted. Therefore, I tried decrypting it (like your `https_handler`) but the problem with that is the backend expects encrypted traffic and gives a Bad Gateway error.

Comment: They key in the first example is the `src` option on the `server` lines.